# How to do a double loop in R?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a list of dataframe (6 sub-dataframes) and a list of self-defined function (func1~func5).
Is there any concise way to write a double loop so that each dataframes can be passed to each function with the expected output a large list?

I have tried below but couldn't work

```
df_list <- (mget(paste0('df',1:6)))
func_list <- list(func1, func2, func3, func4, func5)
df_func <- lapply(df_list, func_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try double `lapply` which would be similar to double `for` loop.

```
result <- lapply(df_list, function(x) lapply(func_list, function(f) f(x)))
```

Every dataframe in `df_list` will be applied every function in `func_list`.

Comment: This is wrong. The inner lapply needs to iterate over func_list: lapply(func_list, function(f) f(x)).